# How to convert an array of objects to object with key value pairs

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I want to convert an array of objects to object with key value pairs in javascript.

```
var arr=[{"name1":"value1"},{"name2":"value2"},...}];
```

How can i convert it to an object such as

```
{"name1":"value1","name2":"value2",...}
```

I want it to be supported in majority of browsers.

Answer (score 77, accepted):

You could use [`Object.assign`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign) and a [spread syntax `...`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_operator) for creating a single object with the given array with objects.

```js
var array = [{ name1: "value1" }, { name2: "value2" }],
    object = Object.assign({}, ...array);
    
console.log(object);
```

Comment: There are a few good uses for Object.assign even with object spread being available, and this is one of them.

Answer (score 7):

You could run a reduce over the array and return a new object. But it is important to remember that if properties are the same they will be overwritten.

```
const newObject = array.reduce((current, next) => {
  return { ...current, ...next};
}, {})
```

If you are using es5 and not es6:

```
var newObject = array.reduce(function(current, next){
  return Object.assign({}, current, next);
}, {})
```

Comment: This is very inefficient (quadratic time, lots of intermediate objects), which can be fixed by using `Object.assign(current, next)` instead of `Object.assign({}, current, next)`.

Answer (score 5):

With modern JS (YMMV):

1. Split each object into entries
2. Aggregate all entries into one object

```js
const arr = [{name1:"value1"}, {name2:"value2"}, {a:1,b:2}];
const obj = Object.fromEntries(arr.flatMap(Object.entries));
console.log(obj);
```

Comment: Object.fromEntries and Array::flatMap are both slow

Answer (score 3):

Try this simple logic

```js
var arr=[{"name1":"value1"},{"name2":"value2"}];
var obj = {}; //create the empty output object
arr.forEach( function(item){ 
   var key = Object.keys(item)[0]; //take the first key from every object in the array
   obj[ key ] = item [ key ];  //assign the key and value to output obj
});
console.log( obj );
```

Comment: For short arrays and ES5 env, this seems the most readable/simple way

Answer (score 3):

use with [`Array#forEach`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) and [`Object.keys`](https://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwi02ai2usHTAhXKPI8KHVxEBF4QFggiMAA&url=https%3A%2F%2Fdeveloper.mozilla.org%2Fen%2Fdocs%2FWeb%2FJavaScript%2FReference%2FGlobal_Objects%2FObject%2Fkeys&usg=AFQjCNHxNfTCTiOC4tCXBdJjQ2o4l76MOw&sig2=rwlchGPKBKd1xFOjBQBbBQ)

```js
var arr = [{"name1": "value1"},{"name2": "value2"}];
var obj = {};
arr.map(k => Object.keys(k).forEach(a => obj[a] = k[a]))
console.log(obj)
```

Comment: A map method returns a new array, however this function is just being used to mutate `var obj` so a `forEach` is more appropriate.

Comment: `Object.keys(k).forEach(a => obj[a] = k[a])` is a slower, less readable, and less compatible version of `Object.assign(obj, k)`.

Answer (score -1):

Using [for...in](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in) loop **:**

```js
var arr=[{"name1":"value1"},{"name2":"value2"}];

var obj = {};
for (var i in arr) {
  obj[Object.keys(arr[i])] = arr[i][Object.keys(arr[i])];
}

console.log(obj);
```

Using [Array.map()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) method with `ES6` **:**

```js
var arr=[{"name1":"value1"},{"name2":"value2"}];

var obj = {};

arr.map(item => obj[Object.keys(item)] = item[Object.keys(item)]);

console.log(obj);
```

Using [Object.assign()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign) method with `ES6` `spreaqd(...)` assignment **:**

```js
let arr=[{"name1":"value1"},{"name2":"value2"}];

let obj = Object.assign({}, ...arr);

console.log(obj);
```

Answer (score -1):

**Supposing that you have `myObject` and `myArray`**

```js
myObject = {};
myArray = [
    {itemOneKey: 'itemOneValue', itemTwoKey: 'itemTwoValue'},
    {itemThreeKey: 'itemThreeValue'}
];
```

simply try this:

```js
myArray.map(obj => {
  Object.keys(obj).map(key => myObject[key] = obj[key])
});
```

```js
const myObject = {};
const myArray = [
    {itemOneKey: 'itemOneValue', itemTwoKey: 'itemTwoValue'},
    {itemThreeKey: 'itemThreeValue'}
];

myArray.map(obj => {
  Object.keys(obj).map(key => myObject[key] = obj[key])
});

console.log(myObject);
```

Comment: `Object.keys(obj).map(key => myObject[key] = obj[key])` is a slower, less readable, and less compatible version of `Object.assign(myObject, obj)`.

Comment: Who told you? Show me where it is said in the specification