# Convert array of object to object using Javascript

Tags: javascript

I have following input

```
const testObj = [
    {id:1, name: 'name1',role:'Developer'},
    {id:2, name: 'name2',role:'Lead'},
    {id:3, name: 'name3',role:'QA'}
]
```

and i need to get the output in following format

```
{
    Developer: {id:1,name:'name1',role:'Developer'},
    Lead: {id:2,name:'name2',role:'Lead'},
    QA: {id:3,name:'name3',role:'QA'}
}
```

and i tried to write the following code but i am not getting my desired output

```
const convert = (array,role) => {
    var result = {}
    for(let index = 0; index < array.length; index++){
        result[array[index].id] = array[index].name;
    }
    return result;
}
```

and i am calling my method using following code

```
convert(testObj,'role');
```

How do i modify this method to get my desired output **without using Reduce** keyword and all

Comment: What happens if there are two Developers?

Comment: @JonasW.@bambam i mistakenly wrote my output with same role, now i updated my output. please check.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to convert an array of objects to object with key value pairs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43626156/how-to-convert-an-array-of-objects-to-object-with-key-value-pairs)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not far off (if I assume the `role`s in the output should be like the `role`s in the input), but the body of your `for` should be

```
result[array[index].role] = array[index];
```

You were using the `id` rather than the `role`, and grabbing the `name` instead of the entire object.

Also note that there's no need for your second parameter (`role`) in the code you've shown or to go from your original to your new structure:

```js
const testObj = [{id:1, name: 'name1',role:'Developer'},
{id:2, name: 'name2',role:'Lead'},
{id:3, name: 'name3',role:'QA'}]

const convert = (array) => {
  var result = {}
  for (let index = 0; index < array.length; index++) {
    result[array[index].role] = array[index];
  }
  return result
}

console.log(convert(testObj));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {
  max-height: 100% !important;
}
```

We can simplify that a bit with `for-of`, though:

```js
const testObj = [{id:1, name: 'name1',role:'Developer'},
{id:2, name: 'name2',role:'Lead'},
{id:3, name: 'name3',role:'QA'}];

const convert = (array) => {
  const result = {};
  for (const entry of array) {
    result[entry.role] = entry;
  }
  return result;
}

console.log(convert(testObj));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {
  max-height: 100% !important;
}
```

---

Note that [as Jonas W. points out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51114795/convert-array-of-object-to-object-using-javascript/51114822#comment89215819_51114795), your result structure only allows for a single person in each role. You might want to have the object store *arrays* instead:

```js
const testObj = [{id:1, name: 'name1',role:'Developer'},
{id:2, name: 'name2',role:'Lead'},
{id:3, name: 'name3',role:'QA'},
{id:4, name: 'name4',role:'QA'}]

const convert = (array) => {
  var result = {}
  for (let index = 0; index < array.length; index++) {
    var roleArray = result[array[index].role];
    if (!roleArray) {
      roleArray = result[array[index].role] = [];
    }
    roleArray.push(array[index]);
  }
  return result
}

console.log(convert(testObj));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {
  max-height: 100% !important;
}
```

or, again, with `for-of`:

```js
const testObj = [{id:1, name: 'name1',role:'Developer'},
{id:2, name: 'name2',role:'Lead'},
{id:3, name: 'name3',role:'QA'},
{id:4, name: 'name4',role:'QA'}];

const convert = (array) => {
  const result = {}
  for (const entry of array) {
    let roleArray = result[entry.role];
    if (!roleArray) {
      roleArray = result[entry.role] = [];
    }
    roleArray.push(entry);
  }
  return result;
}

console.log(convert(testObj));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {
  max-height: 100% !important;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your code groups the `.name`s by `.id`, you want to group the objects itself by their role:

```
function group(array, key) {
  const result = {};
  for(const obj of array)
    result[ obj[key] ] = obj;
  return result;
}

group(testObj, "role")
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
const testObj = [{id:1, name: 'name1',role:'Developer'},
{id:2, name: 'name2',role:'Lead'},
{id:3, name: 'name3',role:'QA'}];

const convert = (array, role) => {
 let i = 0;
  const output = {};
 for (; i < array.length; i+= 1) {
   output[array[i][role]] = array[i];
  }
  return output;
}

console.log(convert(testObj, 'role'));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with [.reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce)

```
const testObj = [{id:1, name: 'name1',role:'Developer'},{id:2, name: 'name2',role:'Lead'},{id:3, name: 'name3',role:'QA'}],
        result = testObj.reduce((acc, cur) => {
            (acc[cur.role] = acc[cur.role] || []);
            acc[cur.role]=cur;
            return acc;
        }, {});
        
    console.log(result);
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).