# How to merge all json objects into one cruly braces in angular

Tags: javascript, json

I have got the following JSON output in angular as the user submit all the survey form
let json_ = JSON.stringify(NJson);
[{"sex":"Female"},{"origin":"Far East and South-East Asia"},{"profession":"An artist of a kind"},{"wkdact":"Netflix and Chill"},{"tastebud":"Comfort/soul food for me."},{"vacation":"Exotic Beaches"},{"instinct":"Packaging"}]

I want to convert this JSON to:
{"sex":"Female","origin":"Far East and South-East Asia","profession":"An artist of a kind","wkdact":"Netflix and Chill","tastebud":"Comfort/soul food for me.","vacation":"Exotic Beaches","instinct":"Packaging"}}
How can I do this in angular ?
or python any suggestion

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to convert an array of objects to object with key value pairs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43626156/how-to-convert-an-array-of-objects-to-object-with-key-value-pairs)

Answer (score 1):

use `Object.assign` for merge array of object in single object.

```
let json=[
    { "sex": "Female" }, 
    { "origin": "Far East and South-East Asia" }, 
    { "profession": "An artist of a kind" }, 
    { "wkdact": "Netflix and Chill" }, 
    { "tastebud": "Comfort/soul food for me." }, 
    { "vacation": "Exotic Beaches" }, 
    { "instinct": "Packaging" }
]

console.log(Object.assign({}, ...json))
```