# Convert object of arrays to Array of object with key value pairs

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have an object of arrays

```
{Cost One: Array(1), Cost Two: Array(1), Cost Five: Array(1)}
    Cost One: Array(1)
    0: "22"
    length: 1

    Cost Two: Array(1)
    0: "33"
    length: 1

    Cost Five: Array(1)
    0: "1456"
    length: 1
```

Desired output :

```
[{Cost One: "22"}, {Cost Two: "33"}, {Cost Five: "1456"}]
```

My code to convert :

```
const mappedDataArray = [];

for (const key in costsFormValues) {
    const mappedData = {
      ...costsFormValues[key]
    };
mappedDataArray.push(mappedData);
}
```

Output :

```
[{…}, {…}, {…}]

0: {0: "22"}
1: {0: "33"}
2: {0: "1456"}
```

**Here instead of 0, how do i add key name that is Cost One and so on**

What am i making wrong here ?

Comment: refer this post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43626156/how-to-convert-an-array-of-objects-to-object-with-key-value-pairs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not setting keys anywhere according to output. It would be something like this:

```js
const costsFormValues = {
  "Cost One":[22],
  "Cost Two":[33],
  "Cost Three":[1456],
}

const mappedDataArray = [];


for (const key in costsFormValues) {
    const mappedData = {
      [key]:costsFormValues[key][0]
    };
mappedDataArray.push(mappedData);
}

console.log(mappedDataArray)
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
let costsFormValues = {
  "Cost One":[22],
  "Cost Two":[33],
  "Cost Three":[1456],
}

let result = Object.keys(costsFormValues).map(key => ({[key]: costsFormValues[key][0].toString()}));
console.log(result);
```