# How to loop an array of objects without index as field in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, loops, indexing

I have to arrange a list of orders, then after have the data ready, this list of objects need to be inserted in another object.

I created a simplified code for better comprehension:

```js
const orderList = [];

orderList.push({
    order1: { desc: "smt1" }
})

orderList.push({
    order2: { desc: "smt2" }
})

const result = {
    anotherVar1: 1,
    anotherVar2: 2,
    ...orderList
}
console.log("result", result)
```

###### Output

```json
{
    '0': { order1: { desc: 'smt1' } },
    '1': { order2: { desc: 'smt2' } },
    anotherVar1: 1,
    anotherVar2: 2,
}
```

###### Desired output:

```json
{
    order1: { desc: 'smt1' },
    order2: { desc: 'smt2' },
    anotherVar1: 1,
    anotherVar2: 2,
}
```

How to achieve the desired output?

Comment: Instead of `orderList.push`, do `orderList.order1 = ...`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want `orderList` to be an object, not an array.  Then instead of using `push`, you want to set the key/value on the object.

```js
const orderList = {};

orderList.order1 = { desc: "smt1" };
orderList.order2 = { desc: "smt2" };

const result = {
    anotherVar1: 1,
    anotherVar2: 2,
    ...orderList
}

console.log('result', result);
```

Answer (score 2):

As [@Rocket Hazmat](https://stackoverflow.com/users/206403/rocket-hazmat) mentions in [his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69726152/5625547), use an object instead off an array

---

To answer the original question, you'll need to convert the array of object to an object before you can 'merge' them

```js
const orderList = [];

orderList.push({ order1: { desc: "smt1" } });
orderList.push({ order2: { desc: "smt2" } });

const result = {
    anotherVar1: 1,
    anotherVar2: 2,
    ...Object.assign({}, ...orderList)
};

console.log('result', result);
```

[How to convert an array of objects to object with key value pairs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43626156/how-to-convert-an-array-of-objects-to-object-with-key-value-pairs)

Answer (score 2):

As a better method keep that array as an object so that you can avoid duplication and additional looping

And as in your same method, you can follow this code to make your desired output

```js
const orderList = [];

orderList.push({
    order1: { desc: "smt1" }
})

orderList.push({
    order2: { desc: "smt2" }
})

const result = {
    anotherVar1: 1,
    anotherVar2: 2,
}
orderList.map(d => {
  for(key in d) {
    result[key] = d[key]
  }
  
})
console.log("result", result)
```

Answer (score 0):

you can try this line without changing your code -

`orderList.map((item) => (result = { ...item, ...result }));`