# How to spread Objects inside Array in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, key-value, spread

I have this array

```
[
  {FirstName: 'Emeka'},
  {MiddleName: 'Praise'},
  {LastName: 'Orji'},
  {Date: 'Today'},
  {Month: 'July'},
  {Year: '2022'},
  {Gender: 'Female'},
  {MaritalStatus: 'married'},
  {State: 'Lagos'},
  {Origin: 'Ape'},
]
```

I want to turn it into an object

```
{
  FirstName: 'Emeka',
  MiddleName: 'Praise',
  LastName: 'Orji',
  Date: 'Today',
  Month: 'July',
  Year: '2022',
  Gender: 'Female',
  MaritalStatus: 'married',
  State: 'Lagos',
  Origin: 'Ape',
}
```

I have been on this for a long time
Pls how can I do this?

Comment: What have you tried to convert the first data-set into the data structure you want?

Comment: @VLAZ, Changed that now, I do have an array but used a function to turn it to an object, so I just thought to post the object directly. Thanks

Comment: `Object.assign({}, ...array)` see: [Object.assign()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign)

Comment: Solution Here  https://stackoverflow.com/a/43626263/1501286

Comment: Yh, just checked it, found my answer already. Plus @pilchard answer here in the comments was the most reasonable and cleanest of them

Comment: `const newObj = origObj.reduce((acc, el) => ({...acc,...el}), {})`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```js
const src = [
  {FirstName: 'Emeka'},
  {MiddleName: 'Praise'},
  {LastName: 'Orji'},
  {Date: 'Today'},
  {Month: 'July'},
  {Year: '2022'},
  {Gender: 'Female'},
  {MaritalStatus: 'married'},
  {State: 'Lagos'},
  {Origin: 'Ape'},
];

const result = src.reduce((collector, item) => {
  Object.assign(collector, item);
  return collector;
}, {});

console.log(result);
```

Comment: just spread into Object.assign as per my comment, this is a reduce call plus n assign calls, vs 1 assign call.

Comment: Yes, that is true, I wished you put this as an answer so more people can access it. It's the cleanest answer to this question.

Comment: It's a duplicate, so it was more appropriate to close

Answer (score 0):

```
let obj = {}
for(let i =0; i< arr.length; i++){
  let o = Object.keys(arr[i])
  obj[o[0]] = arr[i][o[0]]
}
```